# Viewing/Managing number of Firebase listeners in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React Redux application that will have listeners on multiple Firebase Endpoints. These listeners will be mounted and unmounted at various locations on the application and I intend on these being *dynamically* generated based on database changes.

**Questions**

1. Can I view the number of active listeners on the `firebase` object?
2. In the code below, `var firebaseRef` is a reference to the actual `firebase` object correct? Therefore, all listeners are really on the `firebase` object and will not be destroyed if the component unmounts without calling `.off()`?
3. Should I worry about having ~10 active listeners?
4. Does anyone know if not using `.off()` on database references will break code? Or that it will significantly alter performance?

[The Firebase Documentation has it mounted in ComponentWillMount](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/05/using-firebase-with-reactjs.html)

```
componentWillMount: function() {
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('todoApp/items');
this.bindAsArray(firebaseRef.limitToLast(25), 'items');
}
```

and removed at `ComponentWillUnmount`

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  this.firebaseRef.off();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Can I view the number of active listeners on the firebase object?

There is no API that returns the number of listeners active in a client. But you can easily just keep a counter yourself.

> 2. In the code below, `var firebaseRef` is a reference to the actual firebase object correct? Therefore, all listeners are really on the firebase object and will not be destroyed if the component unmounts without calling `.off()`?

A `Reference` is really just the information about a location in the database. Keeping them around is very cheap.

> 3. Should I worry about having ~10 active listeners?

The number of listeners is not a big deal. What you should consider is the amount of data you're reading. In general I recommend to only synchronize data that you are (either actively or frequently) showing to the user.

> 4. Does anyone know if not using `.off()` on database references will break code? Or that it will significantly alter performance?

Calling `.off()` or not does not break the code. But once you attach a listener to a location with `on()` the data for that location will be synchronized until you call `off()`. Having lots of lingering listeners throughout your app may lead to reading lots of data that your user doesn't see.